# Kubernetes generating dynamic config files

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to generate dynamic configuration files (redis, database) based on values (`ex.redis_host`) collected from env variables which will differ from service to service and put it on a specific location (`config/redis.yml`).

How will i be able to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic Config file generation can include creation of

1. **Config file structure**:

   The config files for e.g redis.yaml might varry for development, staging, production environments.
   eg:

   staging

   ```
   ${ENVIRONMENT}:
       host: ${REDIS_HOST}
       namespace: ${REDIS_NAMESPACE}
       port: 6379
   ```

   production:

   ```
   ${ENVIRONMENT}:
       host: ${REDIS_HOST}
       namespace: ${REDIS_NAMESPACE}
       port: 6379
       connect_timeout: ${REDIS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT}
       timeout: {REDIS_TIMEOUT}
   ```
2. **Config file content**:

   The content of the config files could again be populated dynamically.

we could generate `config-templates` or `config-file-structure` using helm and mount them in the required place (say config/redis.yaml ) inside the pod.Then these config-templates can be converted/rendered into proper file using utilities at container run time.

Dynamic creation of config files based on the environment/environment_variables could be achieved using following ways.

**The Bash Way** (using `eval` and `cat`):

1. Create a file named `inator` with the following content

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   eval "cat <<EOF 
   $(<$1)
   EOF
   " | tee $1 >/dev/null
   ```
2. Make inator as executable and place it inside the docker image and execute it as a ENTRYPOINT script
3. Considering the env varibles are avilable inside the pod/container

   eg:
   staging

   ```
   $ env
   ENVIRONMENT=staging
   REDIS_HOST=abc.com
   REDIS_NAMESPACE=inator

   $ cat config/redis.yaml
   ${ENVIRONMENT}:
      host: ${REDIS_HOST}
      namespace: ${REDIS_NAMESPACE}
      port: 6379

   $ ./inator config/redis.yaml
   $ cat config/redis.yaml
   staging:
     host: abc.com
     namespace: inator
     port: 6379
   ```

   production

   ```
   $ env
   ENVIRONMENT=production
   REDIS_HOST=redis.prod.com
   REDIS_NAMESPACE=prod
   REDIS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5
   TIMEOUT=10

   $ cat config/redis.yaml
   ${ENVIRONMENT}:
      host: ${REDIS_HOST}
      namespace: ${REDIS_NAMESPACE}
      port: 6379
      connect_timeout: ${REDIS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT}           
      timeout: {REDIS_TIMEOUT}

   $ ./inator config/redis.yaml
   $ cat config/redis.yaml
   production:
     host: redis.prod.com
     namespace: prod
     port: 6379
     connect_timeout: 5
     timeout: 10
   ```

Advantages:
no additional package required.

**The dockerize way**:

[dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize) is a utility to simplify running applications in docker containers. It internally uses go templates to populate config files from environment variabels.

Have a look at this blog post [Environment Variable Templates](http://steveadams.io/2016/08/18/Environment-Variable-Templates.html) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [helm](https://helm.sh/) can help you out here. Helm allows you to template your k8s yaml files and bundle them into one deployable k8s package. 
Your configuration files might be placed in ConfigMaps and can also be templated with helm. How this is done in detail can be seen in the [chart template guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/tree/master/docs/chart_template_guide).

One way to fill these templates at deploy time then would be:

```
helm upgrade --install my-service /path/to/my/chart/package --set my.value=${MY_VALUE_ENV_VAR}
```

Comment: Thanks!. Instead of specifying the values at run time, is it possible to get the values from Vault so that it will automatically get pre filled.

Comment: @DanielSagayaraj You mean your pods are directly pulling secrets from vault when they start up? In that case you could incorporate consul-template with [exec-mode](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template#exec-mode), which is specifically designed for containers. You could place the consul-template file in a config map, mount it into the container and let consul-template do its magic with vault, when the container starts.